# Adding 2 requirements to a if/else funciton

Tags: php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername']) and ($_SESSION['recht']!=30){
      echo  ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
      window.alert('U bent niet bevoegt voor deze applicatie')
      window.location.href='../home.php'
      </SCRIPT>");
  }
  else {
      //Echo the page
  }
?>
```

I want to make a page secure by using the following requirements:
You must have filled the `$_SESSION['myusername']` and You can only login when `$_SESSION['recht']` is equal to 30.

I can't get this to work. I would really appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: `$_SESSION['recht']` being 30 won't do much to make it more secure. Session IDs should be secure, random strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername']) or $_SESSION['recht']!=30) {

....

}
```

You have forgotten the closing `)` / Have openend one you didn't need. It should work like this.

And you need to terminate your javascript lines:

```
window.alert('U bent niet bevoegt voor deze applicatie');
window.location.href='http://www.domain.com/home.php';
```

Since html5 you can use

```
 <script></script>
```

instead of

```
<script language='JavaScript'></script>
```

as javascript is default for the script tag now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `or` instead of `and`. Just think about the sentence:

"Show an error message `if` they haven't set a username `or` if recht is not 30"

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But it needs to fit both of the requirements. So if i use a "or" only one of them has to be correct right?

Comment: No, because you have the 'error' case first. Try it and see. Read it aloud - Show an error message when either one condition OR the other are false.

If you switch the order of the conditions around, you can change the code to ` if (isset($_SESSION['myusername']) and ($_SESSION['recht']==30)){`